# How to change from PDU to text mode in Android?

Tags: android, sms, pdu

The SMS of the Android send the message in PDU format.
Is there a way to send SMS in text mode?

Answer (score 1):

SMS always being sent in PDU format internally. But there are some API's which will encode it for you, to send text messages use [android.telephony.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)